# Taxa de crescimento do PIB no R

Tags: r

Estou usando o código

```
pib <- BETS.get(22099)
```

Para puxar o *PIB*, acontece que ele puxa de *1995* a *2017*, e só preciso de *2007,01* à *2013,12*. Como eu faço para puxar somente o período que preciso para o modelo? Pois depois preciso usar o código

```
dpib <- (((pib+lag(pib,-1)+lag(pib,-2)+lag(pib,-3))/4)/
  ((lag(pib,-4)+lag(pib,-5)+lag(pib,-6)+lag(pib,-7))/4)-1)*100
```

Para saber qual foi a variação do *PIB* no período. Obrigado.

Comment: Use o comando `?BETS.get`. Ele vai te mostrar como determinar os períodos inicial e final para o acesso dos dados.